# "Has an answer been found" posted as answer

Tags: discussion, support

I'm sure this has been asked before but I was unable to find it.

How are you supposed to handle answers that are just someone asking if a solution has been found?  Example: [iPhone UIWebView epubs split page by page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379411/iphone-uiwebview-epubs-split-page-by-page/2707183#2707183)

The answers I've thought of are:

- Down vote the answer: You take a reputation hit and the user may never return or if they do you may never return to the answer to change your vote.
- Leave a comment: The user may never return and the answer will remain.
- Flag the post for moderator: This doesn't seem like the appropriate use of flagging.  This isn't anything "[exceptional](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)".
- Down vote and leave comment: This has all the same issues as downvoting and leaving a comment.

Comment: If in doubt in using mod flags, do it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flag it for moderator attention.

(I went ahead and deleted it)

Comment: In case you are bored, here are some more posts that could be deleted: http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/343/was-this-ever-resolved (and that is just the tip of the iceberg)

Comment: I got tired after doing about 20 :)

Answer (score 0):

Was this by the person who asked the question or by someone else?

If the former, it sounds pretty useless (unless they were trying to bump the question), and therefore should be deleted.

If the latter, was the person lacking in reputation to leave a comment? If so, I'm happy with "No comments for you" and therefore deleting the "answer". If not, they should be told that they ought to upvote, leave a comment or place a bounty.

Comment: It was by someone else but I don't remember what their reputation was.